# What registry key do I need to change to remove "Group By" Downloads folder searches?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Nearly every guide or discussion on this topics is about manually changing the view with the Windows Explorer ribbon which doesn't work (or doesn't last at least). I plan to write a hack to change the registry and monitor it so it doesn't change back, but I don't know where to look. So far I found this in another guide somewhere:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes

The subkeys in that area are full of "groupby" options and I'm tempted to go through each and change them all to none, but that seems a bit sloppy (though I'm really tempted and might go that way if I don't get another answer).

Bottom line, I despise the GroupBy function and if I ever do want it, I can turn it on myself. Every auto-selected instance of it is wrong and I want to fix it.

Comment: Why don't you just `right click->group by->none`?

Comment: For one, it doesn't work. It resets a single view and then the next time I search or the next day or something, it returns.

Comment: You can set a view to apply to all folders.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. Also, the POINT is to create a registry hack for this. I'm building a tool to allow users to turn off various Windows annoyances and this is one of them. Having a manual process completely defeats the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the entries under:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes`

are the machine-wide defaults, and it's a good idea to leave those intact. IIRC, you have to deal with ownership & permissions issues to edit them, and any edits you make are likely to be wiped out by an update.

---

---

Before going into the various registry mods, you should trouble-shoot why `Apply to Folders` doesn't seem to be working. It's quite effective in the absence of the following issues:

1. **Maxed out on saved views.** The default maximum for saved views is 5000. If you've hit this, saved views begin to disappear as `explorer.exe` will delete a previously saved view to make room for
   a new one. To check, copy and paste the following command into
   **PowerShell** window, then press `<Enter>`to execute.

   ```
   ((gp "HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count
   ```

   It will return the number of views that have been indexed in `BagMRU`:

   [image]

   If that number is `5000`, you need to delete these two registry keys:

   - `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU`
   - `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`

   ***Be aware, this deletes all saved views***.

   Because `Explorer` caches a lot of settings, you should perform these, and subsequent edits, with all `Explorer` windows closed and sign out and back in afterwards. The quicker shell restart is always tempting, but I've seen things get squirrelly with repeated edits/shell restarts.
2. **Undesired dialog views were saved before `Apply to Folders` was executed**. When you execute `A2F` for a given `FolderType`, it
   creates a binary verion of the ProertyBag for the view and saves it
   under:

   - `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults`

   in a FolderTypeID-named REG_BINARY value. The FolderTypeID for `Downloads` is `{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}`.

   It then deletes all the `Explorer` views that use that FolderType, which ensures that your custom default is applied the next time the folder is viewed. ***But the Common Dialog views are not deleted***, so their saved (and likely undesired) views are retained. So to ensure dialog views also use your custom default, run the following **PowerShell** command to delete *all* views that use the `Downloads` FolderType:

   ```
   ( gci 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' -s | ? PSChildName -eq '{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}' ) | ri -Recurse
   ```

   Sign out, Sign back in. Test.

---

---

### Registry Mods to Alter Default Behavior

- **Machine-Wide**

  ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}]
   "Mode"=dword:00000004
   "GroupView"=dword:00000000
  ```

  If you want different icon modes for the dialogs, you need a couple of additional keys:

  ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   ; override GroupBy Date in Downloads FolderType

   ;
   ; Icon mode can be modified, but some also requre LogicalViewMode and IconSize. Study 
   : existing Bags for examples. 
   ;Name        LVM Mode Vid                                    IconSize
   ;----        --- ---- ---                                    --------
   ;Details     1   4    {137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16
   ;Tiles       2   6    {65F125E5-7BE1-4810-BA9D-D271C8432CE3} 48
   ;SmIcons     3   1    {089000C0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16..31
   ;Icons(M-XL) 3   1    {0057D0E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 33..256
   ;List        4   3    {0E1FA5E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16
   ;Content     5   8    {30C2C434-0889-4C8D-985D-A9F71830B0A9} 32


   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\ComDlg\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}]
   @="Downloads"
   "Mode"=dword:00000004
   "GroupView"=dword:00000000

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\ComDlgLegacy\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}]
   @="Downloads"
   "Mode"=dword:00000004
   "GroupView"=dword:00000000

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}]
   @="Downloads"
   "Mode"=dword:00000004
   "GroupView"=dword:00000000
  ```
- **Per-User**

  The above `.reg` files can be converted to per-user modifications by performing a search & replacde, replaceing:

  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
    with
  - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings`

  But the `Shell` settings will be deleted if `A@F` is later executed for the `Downloads` FolderType.

Comment: This is probably the best and most complete answer I've every had. Thank you! I've been struggling with the bags for a while since I want to see if I can come up with a user-specific answer instead of forcing it on everyone, though my target are single-user computers anyway so it might not matter. Either way, I can't seem to get any consistency on the bags for search. It seems there's no clear numbering scheme nor do changes in Windows Explorer reflect in the registry even after doing F5. It's confusing, but I'm going to do some tests with your stuff and see what happens.

Comment: I tried removing all bags, running your PS1 script, and adding the registry keys. It seems that does prevent groupby in download well enough, but when I do a search, it's still grouped by date. This is the core issue that I was talking about - no matter what settings I choose, the downloads folder searches default to groupby

Comment: I re-tested deletiion of `BagMRU`/`Bags`, creation of `HKLM\...\AllFolders\...`, followed by a re-start. That eliminated grouping in both `Downloads` and `Search Results in Downloads`. If you're using the `HKLM` option, try creating a new user account and test the behavior there.

Comment: I finally got time to continue this project, but it's not working. Either in HKLM or HKCU. Maybe the way I constructed the commands in C# aren't correct. Do you have a working CMD or PS script that adds the values correctly that I can use to compare?

Comment: Ok, scratch that. It was because it had saved the view in bags which takes precedence apparently. This will be a somewhat more complex query since I'll have to check all those, but so be it. It's worth it to turn off this worthless feature! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. In **PowerShell**, you can clear the grouping on any saved views (Bags) with code like this: `'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' , 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' | gci -s | ? PSChildName -like '{*}' | ? Property -contains 'GroupView' | ? { $_.GetValue('GroupView') -eq -1 } | Set-ItemProperty -Name GroupView -Value 0`

Comment: I, too, am annoyed by the persistent Grouping in File Explorer.  However, when I go through the process you outline, I have no relevant entries in HKLM. If I do a search for `GroupView`, I find 1380 instances of `GroupView`.  One in HKCU, One in HK_USERS (both seeming to do with Desktop), and the rest are all in HKCR. This is Windows 11. Not sure what to do next. Perhaps try to figure out if all the Values are 0 or something else.

Comment: To avoid confusion and unintended results, you should limit your serching & editing to `HKCU` and `HKLM`. `HKCR` exists only in memory for the currently logged in user. All entires under `HKCR`  come from either `HKCU\Software\Classes` or `HKCU\Software\Classes`, which are persistant. And any entries you find under `HKU` pertaining to your profile can be viewed/edited from `HKCU`. Not sure what tool you're using to serch the registry (I know REgEdit doesn't return a count) or the exact nature of your search.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the **Downloads** folder under **This PC**
2. Set view options to your liking
3. From the `View` tab, open the `Folder Options` dialog
4. Selct the `View` tab in the dialog and click **`Apply to Folders`**
5. Close **Explorer**, reopen, and execute a test search

Comment: This is the manual process that I mentioned that's easy to find, but doesn't work. Thanks, but I need a registry hack, not a manual process.

Comment: It's a shame you couldn't be more precise. "Manual process" is pretty vague. I had no idea if you were aware of `Apply to Folders` or had merely turned off grouping for a single view. I'll add an answer with useful trfouble-shooting info and a couple of options for registry modification.