Prevent File Open dialog from grouping files
How can I prevent the File Open dialog from grouping files and folders by date modified?
Here I wish to navigate to one of many subfolder in Downloads, which conventionally appears at the top of the list when sorted by name or type. However as the contents of the folder are unhelpfully grouped into "Today", "Earlier this week", "Last week" etc, the subfolder is not at the top of the list where it should be.


Right-click on any blank space in the main section of that window and you'll get a menu allowing you to change the layout, including a "Group By" option to change (or stop) grouping.
This option does not appear to save the layout in my brief testing. I'm looking to see how to save these changes now.

Cool. I'd tried making the change in File Explorer and telling it to apply the changes everywhere, but that didn't stick.

The following steps appear to have worked, on a PC where I have local admin privileges:

In regedit, take control of this container:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

right-click {0000..., Permissions, Advanced
where Owner: SYSTEM click "Change"
under "Enter the object name to select" enter your Windows/Microsoft username, or "Administrators" for the local admin group
click "Check names" to search, select the appropriate match, press OK


Assign Full Control of {885a...}/TopViews/{0000...} to yourself or the Administrators group

right-click {0000..., Permissions
select the Administrators group or click Add and find your user account the same way as before
tick the "Full Control / Allow" checkbox


Change {885a...}/TopViews/{0000...}/GroupBy and erase System.DateModified:

right-click, Modify (or double-click)
erase text (i.e. "System.DateModified" in the "Value data" field
click OK



For the Current User, "delete all views that use the Downloads FolderType" in PowerShell:

( gci 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' -s | ? PSChildName -eq '{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}' ) | ri -Recurse


Sign out and sign in again
File Open dialog should no longer be grouped by Date Modified!

885a... is the GUID for the Downloads folder specifically.
Sources:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/completely-disable-file-grouping-always-everywhere/ac31a227-f585-4b0a-ab2e-a557828eaec5
https://superuser.com/a/1678636/677515
